# bash - multiple operations without temp files (counting lines of code with custom exclusions)

Tags: bash, count

I want to keep each operation on its own line with interspersed comments

is there anyway to do this without the kludgy temp files

```
    #!/bin/sh

    git diff --stat `git hash-object -t tree /dev/null` > tmp.txt

    # not my code
    grep -v "^ kazmath" tmp.txt > tmp2.txt

    grep -v "\.obj " tmp2.txt > tmp.txt
    grep -v "\.png " tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
    grep -v "\.gbo " tmp2.txt > tmp.txt

    # not my code
    grep -v "obj2opengl\.pl " tmp.txt > tmp2.txt

    grep -v "\.txt " tmp2.txt > tmp.txt
    grep -v "\.md " tmp.txt > tmp2.txt
    grep -v "\.blend " tmp2.txt > tmp.txt

    # +'s at end of line
    sed 's/+*$//' tmp.txt > tmp2.txt

    # ditch last line
    sed '$d' < tmp2.txt > tmp.txt

    echo -n "lines of code "
    cut -d '|' -f 2 tmp.txt | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}'

    rm tmp.txt
    rm tmp2.txt
```

Comment: You can use tee and fifos... And bash has a special syntax for shell-managed tempfiles: <(commands) and >(commands) (known as _process substition_)

Comment: tees and fifos how? process substitution?? how?

Comment: It's funny how people spoil the symmetry by using `tmp.txt` and `tmp2.txt` instead of using `tmp1.txt` and `tmp2.txt`.

Comment: symmetry like life is an illusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pipes and more powerful regular expressions with `grep -E` (aka `egrep`):

```
git diff --stat `git hash-object -t tree /dev/null` |
grep -v "^ kazmath" |
grep -E -v "\.(png|gbo|obj|txt|md|blend) " |
grep -v "obj2opengl\.pl " |
sed -e 's/+*$//' -e '$d' |
cut -d '|' -f 2 |
awk '{sum += $1 } END { print "lines of code " sum }'
```

Comment: can comments go in between those pipes? (see question) - YES i didnt think they could! thanks! nice grep-ing!

Comment: Yes, you can insert comments into shell scripts - including between stages of a pipeline.  With the possible exception of the `sed` and `cut` commands, they're near enough self-explanatory, so I'm not sure comments are warranted, but they are most certainly permitted.

Comment: you can also write in a single command awk or perl, for example perl -nle 'next if /^ kazmath|\.(obj|png|gbo|txt|md|blend) |obj2opengl\.pl /;s/\+*$//;last if eof;$sum+=(split/\|/)[1];END{print $sum;}'

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul: With Perl, TMTOWTDI (There's more than one way to do it).  You're right.  With a bit more exercise of the brain, the three `grep` operations could probably be combined into one, too.  The suggested solution shown was an easy step up from the temporary files in the question.  It's unlikely to be a production performance show-stopper; if it was, then I'd probably use Perl myself.

Comment: I sure a single line of perl is very clever, however I did mention I wanted each step separate (for ease of editing, clarity and commenting) Jonathan Leffler's answer fits the question much better